# Downloading plist with ASIHTTPRequest works only partially

Tags: iphone, objective-c, save, plist, asihttprequest

I have a game where there are different categories to play with. These categories are basically plist files. So, if in the future, I want to add plists, the user should be able to download a plist and play new levels. So what I am aiming for is:

- Download .plist from URL
- Save .plist file in documents directory on iphone (forever)
- use .plist

Here is what I did and it works (console logs "finished !!"), but if I check whether the file is in the documents directory, there is no response (the boolean fileExists stays NO).

```
-(void)startGame:(id)sender{
    NSArray *categoriesArray = [[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton] categoriesArray];
    NSString *category = [NSString stringWithFormat:[categoriesArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]];


    NSString *thePath = [mainPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",category]];
    NSDictionary *categoryPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:thePath];

    if(categoryPlist != nil){
        [[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton]setCurrentCategory:category];
        [[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton]updateHexCountAndInitalTime];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:TRANSITIONDURATION scene:[LevelSets scene]]]; 
    }
    else{

        [self plistForCategory:category];
        NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *myCategory= [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",category]];
        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myCategory];
        if(fileExists == YES){
            [[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton]setCurrentCategory:category];
            [[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton]updateHexCountAndInitalTime];
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:TRANSITIONDURATION scene:[LevelSets scene]]]; 
            NSLog(@"category exists now");
        }
    }


}



-(void)plistForCategory:(NSString*)category
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.tinycles.com/wannaplay/plists/%@.plist",category]];

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:documentsDirectory];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];


}


- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
    NSLog(@"finished !!");
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Download failed. This is why.
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is because you're starting an async request, so if the request has not finished, your `if(fileExist==YES)` still returns NO; i suggest you in this case to start a sync request:

```
- (IBAction)startRequest:(id)sender
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:LINK_TO_PLIST];
  ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request setDownloadDestinationPath:DOC_PATH];
  [request startSynchronous];
  NSError *error = [request error];
  if (!error) {
      //start your game after the file is downloaded
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, there is no change whatsoever... :(

Comment: I've update my answer, probably the if always returns no, because the file has not yet been downloaded, have you tried using a synchronous request?

Comment: Yes I have tried it... How long could it take to download this file ? Because quite honestly, I have no idea where the problem could be...

Comment: Usually a synchronous request is used for small files and this will block the main thread. Otherwise, if you want to use an asynchronous request so as not block the main thread, you should start your game until you have completely downloaded the levels file.